# Convert sql query to SQLALCHEMY. Problem in "as" keyword in "join" query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to convert this sql query to SQLALCHEMY:

```
SELECT * FROM dbcloud.client_feedback as a
join (select distinct(max(submitted_on)) sub,pb_channel_id pb, mail_thread_id mail from client_feedback group by pb_channel_id, mail_thread_id) as b
where (a.submitted_on = b.sub and a.pb_channel_id = b.pb) or ( a.submitted_on = b.sub and a.mail_thread_id = b.mail )
```

I can't find `as` keyword in SQLALCHEMY

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you may be looking for is `.label(name)`.

Assuming you have a model

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column()
```

here is an example of how `.label(name)` can be used

```
 query = db.session.query(MyModel.name.label('a'))
```

will produce the SQL

```
 SELECT my_model.name as a FROM my_model
```